When the same alias is used twice, which one will subsequent references point to?
There is a query that joins the same table twice with the same alias (but under different conditions). To which of the two data sets will subsequent references to this alias point?
SELECT ...
  FROM table_1
  JOIN table_2 A ON ...
  JOIN table_3 A ON ...
  JOIN table_4 B ON A.col_1 = B.col_1

A simple experiment I conducted with the following query:
  WITH
    test_1 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_2 AS (SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_3 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_4 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c ON a.col_1 = c.col_1;

Result:



col_1
col_1
col_1
col_1




1
null
1
null


2
2
2
2



Suggests that the join of the table test_4 is associated with the first occurrence of the alias. Meanwhile, all chatbots are confident that the last mentioned alias should be used. Therefore, a "carved in stone" rule will be needed to justify the bug fix (since the experiment might not cover all possible behavior scenarios). So, according to the "rules," which alias should be used when it's referenced twice in Oracle?

From my point of view, your best option is: do NOT use the same alias twice.

@Littlefoot thank you for this advice. This is exactly what I'm trying to resolve in legacy query. In case we replace "a" aliases to "a1" and "a2" then which one we should use to replace in test_4 table join condition to have same behavior of the query?

The way you put it, that would be "a1", i.e. FROM test_1 b   LEFT JOIN test_2 a1 ON a1.col_1 = b.col_1   LEFT JOIN test_3 a2 ON a2.col_1 = b.col_1   LEFT JOIN test_4 c  ON a1.col_1 = c.col_1

Like the most recently defined a?

@jarlh nope, seems like the very first one in this test case. May be it's randomly chosen in each different query :)

I hope you're just asking this question "hypothetically" because it's just against any good practice and common sense....  . If you plan on writing such code, don't. If you run into such code, fix it.

If you give the columns unambiguous identifiers then the table alias will refer to the alias that corresponds to the table (or inline-view) with the appropriate column identifier. For example, if you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE test_1 (col_1) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_2 (col_2) AS
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_3 (col_3) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_4 (col_4) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

Then:
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a ON a.col_2 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a ON a.col_3 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c1 ON a.col_2 = c1.col_4
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c2 ON a.col_3 = c2.col_4;

is the same as:
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a1 ON a1.col_2 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a2 ON a2.col_3 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c1 ON a1.col_2 = c1.col_4
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c2 ON a2.col_3 = c2.col_4;

and both output:



COL_1
COL_2
COL_3
COL_4
COL_4




1
null
1
null
1


3
3
null
3
null


2
2
null
2
null


4
null
4
null
null



In that case the a alias used depends on the subsequent column identifier and a.col_2 and a.col_3 refer to different a aliases.

If you have ambiguous columns:
CREATE TABLE test_1 (col_1) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_2 (col_1) AS
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_3 (col_1) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test_4 (col_1) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

Then the query:
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c ON a.col_1 = c.col_1;

is the same as:
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a1 ON a1.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a2 ON a2.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c ON a1.col_1 = c.col_1;

and both output:



COL_1
COL_1
COL_1
COL_1




2
2
null
2


3
3
null
3


4
null
4
null


1
null
1
null



Where a.col_1 is ambiguous but appears to be resolved as the first instance of the a table alias that contains a col_1 column identifier.
Oracle Fiddles: 11gR2, 18, 21, 23



first instance of the a table alias that contains a col_1 column identifier
That's it, thanks! My experiment above gave me the same conclusion, but I wanted to hear it from others to be sure. What if it's random after all, and under different conditions the experiment would have given a different result.



@ВиталийЯндулов "What if it's random after all" The best answer is to work out what business logic was intended to be implemented and implement that. If your previous answer was correct then make sure your new code gives the same output.
